# Display age on selecting date from date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written following jQuery for calculating age when user selects date from date picker and the focus of `textbox(#dobfield)` is lost then the calculated age should get displayed on `textbox (#age)`.

```
 function GetAge(dateString) {
      var today = new Date();
      var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
      var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
      var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
      if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
          age--;
      }
      return age;
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#dobfield").onblur(function() {
          var dob = $("#dobfield").val().trim();
          var calculatedDob = GetAge(dob);
          $("#age").text(calculatedDob);
      });
  });
```

The html is as

```
        <input aria-required="true" id="dobfield" class="form-control" required="" type="text" onclick="css()">
        <input type="text" id="age" class="form-control" required>
```

The above code is not working!!!

Please help !!!

Comment: include all relevant code to OP

Comment: Let us know what's not working.

Comment: age is calculated but is not displayed in age textbox

Comment: `.on("blur",function()` ?

Comment: Show your html then we can help you why its not displayed.

Comment: This is a typo. There's no `.onblur()` function. It should be either `.blur()` or `.on("blur")`. If you had checked your console for errors, it would have said you.

Comment: @Nida This is a typo.

Comment: @Nida, hope my answer has solved the issue you were facing. If so, you may accept the answer.

Comment: Now if I use  $("#dobfield").blur(function(){... alert(calculatedDob) });... It gets displayed on alert box.... the main problem is that it does not get displayed on textbox (#age). Please help me !!!

Comment: @Nida use `.val()` instead of `.text()` when changing the input.

Comment: @Nida, I have updated my answer. If `#age` is a textbox then use `$('#age').val();` instead of `text()`. I have updated my answer with this change. I hope all the issues would be solved with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the comments and answers here are great. However, the only problem with your code was that you were using the incorrect method to update the textbox.

To change the text of an input field (textbox):

```
$("#inputId").val("new value");
```

To change the text of a different element (label, span, et.c.):

```
$("#otherId").text("new value");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the exact example what you want. This function will calculate age as soon as you change the date from datepicker and it will show the age in the field. In this example `#dob` is datepicker field's id.

```
$('#dob').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(value, ui) {
        var today = new Date(),
            dob = new Date(value),
            age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;

        $('#age').value(age);  // Changed it to `val()` as it is the textbox.
    },
    maxDate: '+0d',
    yearRange: '1920:2010',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/PHvYK/1/)

Comment: @PeterAbolins, it is the value which gets substracted from the year returned by `getFullYear()`. Based on the substraction, we can get exact gap in  numbers of years.

Answer (score 1):

Check it out.

```
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />



<input type="text" name="birthdate" value="10/24/1984" />

<input type="text" id="age" class="form-control" required readonly>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('input[name="birthdate"]').daterangepicker({
                singleDatePicker: true,
                showDropdowns: true
            }, 
            function(start, end, label) {
                var years = moment().diff(start, 'years');
                alert("You are " + years + " years old.");
                $("#age").val("You are " + years + " years old.");
            });
        });
</script>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/m2fdprrL/

Same with appending the result to age field. https://jsfiddle.net/m2fdprrL/2/